# How to solve the Proxy Server 407 error in .NET.CORE

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.net.webexception, webexception

SO i have some code that accesses the html of a website given  it woks but only in visualstudios.Framework for c#   when this code is input into the  app.config.

```
    <system.net> <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" /> </system.net>
```

ps next line between the ><

but i need this code to work in .CORE instead of .FRAMEWORK 
but it gives this error.

System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.'

i tried solving it by creating a app.config from the solution explorer , but to no affect did it work 
all the answers on the internet are either too complicated or it shows that little bit of code i put in the app.config  of .FRAMEWORK which does not work on .Core

the code as a starting point.

```
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;
            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry , somethings faulty");

            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                readStream.ToString();
                // Console.WriteLine(readStream);
            }
            string ImpureTexta = readStream.ReadToEnd().ToString();
            BaseHTML = ImpureTexta;  ///turns ImpureText in class to the actual html code so it can be used by entire program
            Console.WriteLine(BaseHTML);
            Console.WriteLine(" <--------------------------------Extraction  B Complete --------------------------------->");
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

.NET Core does not have `app.config` files. This needs to be configured in code.

use `request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` object you use to make the HTTP call needs to have the above property set, before you call `GetResponse()`. In .NET Core, it will not use settings from an `app.config` file like in .NET Framework.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it needs " handler.UseDefaultCredentials= true;" to work for our proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The following Error:

Message: The proxy tunnel request to proxy 'http://ipv4.xx.xxx.xxx.xx.webdefence.global.blackspider.com:8081/' failed with status code '407'."

Solved with the following NET Core code:

```
  HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            if (useProxy)
            {
                IWebProxy proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
                proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                handler.UseDefaultCredentials= true;
                handler.Proxy = proxy;
            }

            using var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```